Old guy is talking to his (dead?) daughter in prison, but he's alone
An old guy is having a conversation with his daughter (~25-35 yrs old). They're walking around the prison yard. I remember a large green field, but maybe it wasn't that large, and the high prison fences. They slowly walk around the yard, they're happy-ish, reminiscing etc.
The scene ends with a view of him walking alone and then 2 guards talking to each other about how he hasn't had a visitor in 10 years. That's the point you realize he's not actually talking to his daughter. The daughter might be dead and he doesn't know or accept that, but maybe not.
I think it's a pretty well known movie, and not very old (last 10 yrs?). Might actually be a tv show... I've no idea what the rest of the movie was about.

That sounds like the ending of Blow, (2001), with Johnny Depp.  The daughter isn't dead, she has just never visited him all the time he's been in prison.  The scene is on Youtube.

Yes! The green was right, but the rest not exactly =) Thanks. I see the real George will be set free next year!
